# How to implement BackPressed function by OnLongClickListener

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

This is onBackPressed function by onClickListener:

```
onback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Do you have any idea how to implement this by OnLongClickListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is that your mean?

```
onback.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onBackPressed();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

and import:

```
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
```

Comment: I already tried this earlier, it doesn't work. Error is: The method setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}) and fix suggestions such: change to 'setKeyListener' etc

Comment: Yes it works after your edit. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
onback.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
                onBackPressed();
                //finish(); you can also call finish
                return false;
            }
});
```